# Where can I learn about maya hieroglyphs?

Tags: writing-system

I passed my last vacations in Yucatan and was impressed about the Maya culture. Scientists still study and have a lot of open questions. My principal intention is to learn and edit the already known about Mayan hieroglyphs to be able to teach it. Hope this question fits to this community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several resources, especially in book format:

- Sylvanus Griswold Morley: *An Introduction to the Study of the Maya Hieroglyphs*. Smithsonian Institution, Bureau of American Ethnology, Bulletin 57. 1915. This book is now in the public domain; see [Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/An_Introduction_to_the_Study_of_the_Maya_Hieroglyphs) and [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/AnIntroductionToTheStudyOfTheMayaHieroglyphs).
- Mark Pitts: "Writing in Maya Glyphs": available on the [FAMSI website](http://www.famsi.org/research/pitts/index.html).
- Michael D. Coe: *Reading the Maya Glyphs*. [2001] Second revised edition. Thames & Hudson, 2016. (176 pages)
- John Montgomery: *Dictionary of Maya Hieroglyphs*. Hippocrene Books, 2001. 425 pages. You can search this dictionary on the [FAMSI website](http://research.famsi.org/montgomery_dictionary/mt_search.php).
- John Montgomery: *How to Read Maya Hieroglyphs*. Hippocrene Books, 2004. 360 pages. This appeart to be closer to a grammar than a dictionary.
- William Gates: *An Outline Dictionary of Maya Glyphs*. Dover Publications, 2013.

The following are also relevent to maya hieroglyphs, but less appropriate for learning, except for *Understanding Maya Inscriptions*.

- J. Eric S. Thompson: *A Catalog of Maya Hieroglyphs*. University of Oklahoma Press, 1991.
- John F. Harris; Stephen K. Stearns: *Understanding Maya Inscriptions: A Hieroglyph Handbook*. Second revised edition. University of Pennsylvania Museum of Archaeology and Anthropology, 1996.
- John F. Harris: *New and Recent Hieroglyph Readings: A Supplement to Understanding Maya Inscriptions*. University of Pennsylvania Museum of Archaeology and Anthropology, 1993. (Supplement to an earlier edition of the previous book.)
- Martha J. Macri; Matthew G. Looper: *The New Catalog of Maya Hieroglyphs, Volume 1: The Classic Inscriptions*. University of Oklahoma Press, 2013.